# Converting .net sql datetime to jquery using date.js

Tags: sql, jquery, datejs

I have an ajax post to which I am getting values from sql database.  My datatype in sql is datetime what it returns is:

```
Orderdate: "/Date(-62135578800000)/"
```

Now using date.js I am trying to do the following:

```
orderdate = Date.parse(response.d[post].Orderdate);

orderdate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

but that keeps coming up with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null
```

what am i doing wrong? i don't get it :(

EDIT: here's my complete code,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajaxcalls.asmx/Test",
    data: "{id:'" + id + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        for (var post in response.d) {
            orderdate = Date.parse(response.d[post].Orderdate);
            console.log(orderdate);
            console.log(response.d[post].Orderdate);
            console.log(orderdate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Well, if you take away the toString() method and then console.log(Orderdate), it says `Invalid Date`

Comment: but why is it invalid?

Comment: Because of exactly what was said in the answer.

Comment: saw it thanks, almost got it resolved just wondering why its giving me an invalid date now

Comment: is the response an array of objects? If so, I would use a `for(;;;)` loop instead of `for(..in..)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass the .NET JSON date implementation straight to JavaScript `Date.parse()`; you need to extract the milliseconds since epoch out and pass that to the `Date` constructor.

```
var orderdate = new Date(parseInt(response.d[post].Orderdate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));

orderdate.toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
```

for more on the rationale behind the date representation used by ASP.NET, see

> One of the sore points of JSON is the lack of a date/time literal.
>   Many people are surprised and disappointed to learn this when they
>   first encounter JSON. The simple explanation (consoling or not) for
>   the absence of a date/time literal is that JavaScript never had one
>   either: The support for date and time values in JavaScript is entirely
>   provided through the Date object. Most applications using JSON as a
>   data format, therefore, generally tend to use either a string or a
>   number to express date and time values. If a string is used, you can
>   generally expect it to be in the ISO 8601 format. If a number is used,
>   instead, then the value is usually taken to mean the number of
>   milliseconds in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) since epoch, where
>   epoch is defined as midnight January 1, 1970 (UTC). Again, this is a
>   mere convention and not part of the JSON standard. If you are
>   exchanging data with another application, you will need to check its
>   documentation to see how it encodes date and time values within a JSON
>   literal. For example, Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX uses neither of the
>   described conventions. Rather, it encodes .NET DateTime values as a
>   JSON string, where the content of the string is /Date(ticks)/ and
>   where ticks represents milliseconds since epoch (UTC). So November 29,
>   1989, 4:55:30 AM, in UTC is encoded as "/Date(628318530718)/". For
>   some rationale behind this rather contrived choice of encoding, see
>   ["Inside ASP.NET AJAX’s JSON date and time string."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb)

Comment: Ok almost there but for some reason it returns a value of: Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (SA Pacific Standard Time)  when the date in the database is: 2013-03-30 14:37:14.640

Comment: @Andres 2013-03-30 14:37:14.640 represented in milliseconds since epoch should be `1364654234640`. Is this what you see sent to the client? the value of `-62135578800000` is being correctly parsed to Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500.

Comment: nevermind! it worked like a charm, the issue was on my end..thank u so much!